# Where to set the DOCTYPE?

Tags: theming

My zen subtheme doctype is currently !DOCTYPE html and I would like to change this. What is the correct place to add the doctype I want to use?

I copied the html.tpl.php file and pasted it into the templates directory of my subtheme thinking that's where it's set, but it's not being picked up...

Comment: Did you clear the cache after adding the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the correct place (html.tpl.php) to modify the doctype assuming you're using Drupal 7, thats the default theme implementation for altering the basic page structure ([documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7)). In Drupal 6, you're looking for the page.tpl.php file.